# codechef javascript submission

Tags: javascript

how can I submit solutions in Javascript for Codechef questions?

can you give me an example to handle js input at codechef?

www.codechef.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this is for each language a huge hazzle.
The best javascript implementation in Codechef is via node.js. 
This is for the first Exercise "Life, the Universe, and Everything":

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');


process.stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
  var lines = chunk.toString().split('\n');

  lines.forEach(function(line) {
  if (line === '42') {
     process.exit();
  }
     process.stdout.write(line+'\n');

  });
});
```

For me this worked.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_56.

Comment: I agree with you when you say this is a hassle. Another site I like called Codesignal (codesignal.com) has a much simpler IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Codechef uses Rhino Javascript engine to judge solutions. This is how it can be done for JavaScript (rhino-1.7R4).

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(java.lang);

var reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System['in']) );

while(true) {
    var line = reader.readLine();
    if(line == null || line == "42") {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

[here you can find a basic implementation in most of the languages](http://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_35)